# Modifying shading in ridge plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, shading, ggridges

With the `R` code below,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
iris$m <- iris$Sepal.Length-5.5
pp <- aggregate(m ~ Species, iris, function(x) 1-ecdf(x)(0))
names(pp)[2] <- 'P'
dat <- merge(iris[, c('Species', 'm')], pp)
dev.new(width=6, height=3)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = m, y = Species, fill=P)) +
  stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = FALSE, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("blue","cyan","gray","gray","yellow","red"), limits = c(0,1))
```

I get the following ridge plot
[image]

The color indicates the probability or the area under each density curve above zero on the x-axis (i.e., the value in `dat$P`). I want to modify the ridge plot so that, if `dat$P` >=0.5, show the color-coded shading only above 0 on the x-axis; if `dat$P`
< 0.5, show the color-coded shading only below 0 on the x-axis.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably need two different layers here:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = m, y = Species, label = P)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(
    aes(fill = if_else(stat(x) > 0, as.numeric(stat(label)), NA_real_),
        linetype = ''),
    quantile_lines = FALSE, 
    data = dat %>% filter(P > 0.5)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(
    aes(fill = if_else(stat(x) < 0, as.numeric(stat(label)), NA_real_),
        linetype = ''),
    quantile_lines = FALSE, 
    data = dat %>% filter(P < 0.5)) +
  labs(fill = "Proportion > 0") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = scales::alpha(c("blue","cyan","gray","gray",
                                                "yellow","red"), 0.7),
                       limits = c(0,1)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 1, name = "XYS") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(order = 2, override.aes = list(fill = "white",
                                 col = 'white', size = 0)),
         fill = guide_colorbar(order = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help! I assume `library(magrittr)` is required, but I got the following error: `Error in filter(., P > 0.5) : object 'P' not found`

Comment: Sorry, it's library(dplyr) or library(tidyverse) you would need here.

Comment: Thanks again for the nice solution, @Allan Cameron! Do you mind a small follow-up question: is there an easy way to add a label (e.g., `XYS`) at the bottom of the colorbar?

Comment: It depends. Would you still need the label that says "Proportion > 0" at the top? If not, this could be used to say XYS and moved to the bottom. If you want an extra arbitrary label added at the bottom, there are a couple of different ways to do that, but they are a bit hacky.

Comment: I would like to keep the original label on the top while adding another one at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: @bluepole I have added a somewhat hacky solution for adding text here.